# 404 Error at Graylog login

Tags: nginx, vmware, graylog2, graylog

I'm currently trying to get Graylog to work. I installed with the following graylog-settings.json :

local-ip is the graylog server local ip on our network.

graylog.domain.com is our graylog external domain

```
{
  "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
  "smtp_server": "smtp.gmail.com",
  "smtp_port": 465,
  "smtp_user": "xxxx",
  "smtp_password": "xxxx",
  "smtp_from_email": "graylog@graylog",
  "smtp_web_url": "http://graylog",
  "smtp_no_tls": false,
  "smtp_no_ssl": false,
  "master_node": "127.0.0.1",
  "local_connect": false,
  "current_address": "local-ip",
  "last_address": "local-ip",
  "enforce_ssl": false,
  "journal_size": 1,
  "node_id": false,
  "internal_logging": true,
  "web_listen_uri": false,
  "web_endpoint_uri": false,
  "rest_listen_uri": false,
  "rest_transport_uri": false,
  "external_rest_uri": "http://graylog.domain.com:9000/",
  "custom_attributes": {

  }
}
```

We have a PFSense (which I'm whitelisted on every port).

I configured a NAT entry to send all 9000 request on my graylog server.

I configured my NGinx proxy to send all graylog.domain.com to local-ip

Here is the problem :

If I reach graylog.domain.com:80, I can see the login page, but a any login attempt, I get :

> Error - the server returned: 404 - cannot POST
>   http://graylog.domain.com:9000/system/sessions (404)

If I reach graylog.domain.com:9000, I get directly this error (without the login page) :

> We are experiencing problems connecting to the Graylog server running
>   on http://local-ip:9000/api/. Please verify that the server is
>   healthy and working correctly.
>
> You will be automatically redirected to the previous page once we can
>   connect to the server.
>
> Do you need a hand? We can help you.
>
> More details

I RTFM but I can't get the right configuration.. Can anybody help ?

EDIT :

Thanks to @joschi, I manage to get this to work. Here is my conf file now :

```
{
  "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
  "smtp_server": "smtp.gmail.com",
  "smtp_port": 465,
  "smtp_user": "xxx",
  "smtp_password": "xxx",
  "smtp_from_email": "graylog@graylog",
  "smtp_web_url": "http://graylog",
  "smtp_no_tls": false,
  "smtp_no_ssl": false,
  "master_node": "127.0.0.1",
  "local_connect": false,
  "current_address": "local-ip",
  "last_address": "local-ip",
  "enforce_ssl": false,
  "journal_size": 1,
  "node_id": false,
  "internal_logging": true,
  "web_listen_uri": false,
  "web_endpoint_uri": false,
  "rest_listen_uri": false,
  "rest_transport_uri": false,
  "external_rest_uri": "http://external-ip:9000/api/",
  "custom_attributes": {

  }
}
```

And I used the following command to update my conf file :

`sudo graylog-ctl set-external-ip "http://external-ip:9000/api/"`

Of course, external-ip is our public IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `external_rest_uri` setting is wrong. It has to point to the URI of the Graylog REST API.

You're also not supposed to edit the `graylog-settings.json` by hand (unless you really need some advanced settings), but use the `graylog-ctl` command.

Please read http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/configuration/graylog_ctl.html for further information about the `graylog-ctl`command.